# How to create bar chart in r, which has one categorical variable on y axis and continuous variable on x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

```
data <- read.csv("/Users/infinite/Desktop/covid_19_india.csv", header = TRUE)
table(data$State.UnionTerritory)
barplot(table(data$State.UnionTerritory), ylab = 'No. of confirmed cases', main= "Bar plot 
of covid19 cases")
```

But I want to plot confirmed cases variable on x axis and State.UnionTerritory on y axis. I want to use two variables to plot. But the Method i tried using has just one variable with its frequency on y axis. Please help me.

Note : This file has two variable 1. State.UnionTerritory, 2. Confirmed

I want to plot them against each other using bar plot.

Answer (score 1):

You mark this question with the tag ggplot2
In that case the basic code is:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data=data) +
    geom_col(aes(x=confirmed, y=State.UnionTerritory))
```

In base R  think it something liki this

```
barplot(height=data$confirmed, names=data$State.UnionTerritory, horiz=T , las=1)
```

PD: try to avoid name your variables with names used by base R (in this case "data")